# Sending Message To All server

Tags: discord.js, bots

Can anyone help me? I don't know how to do this, but I want to make my bot send a message to every server it is in and if it doesn't have perms to do it, it can just ignore it. How do you do it? Am using discord.js v 12

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question, please.

Comment: I don’t know for sure, but I think if your bot is in a lot of servers, it will be ratelimited, but like I said, I don’t know for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over the servers like this:

```js
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    // Here you can use the guild object to send messages
});
```

Then you have to find a text channel to send the message in, you can achieve this by sending it in the first found text channel in the server like this:

```js
let channelID = null;
const channels = guild.channels.cache;

channelLoop:
for (let key in channels) {
    let c = channels[key];
    if (c[1].type === "text") {
        channelID = c[0];
        break channelLoop;
    }
}
```

And send the message:

```
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(guild.systemChannelID || channelID);
channel.send(`This is a message`); // This is the message you're sending in the server
```